# Displaying tabular data in Android - TableLayout, custom Adapter or both?

Tags: java, android

In the past when I have needed to display large data sets in a table, I've just looped over the data and on every iteration I'd inflate an xml layout representing a TableRow, obtain references to the child controls, set their properties from the data source and add the row to a TableLayout.  When just displaying simple rows of data or items in a grid, I use an adapter.  Am I doing this correctly, or is there a way to use an adapter to display tabular data with column alignment like in a TableLayout?  Or, is there some way to apply the ViewHolder pattern to the way I'm manually adding rows to a TableLayout to avoid the extra calls to inflate xml and get references to child controls (findViewById)?